# json (gson) parse changes the type of data when parsing

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have a json string which looks something like this :

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

When I use gson parser to convert that to a `Map<String,String> map`. The gson converts the type to `Map<String,ArrayList>`. And when I try to print the class name using `System.out.println(map.get("employees").getClass().toString())`. But this throws an exception - `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

**my code looks something like this**

```
String npv = json_string_provided_above;
Map<String,String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
mp = new Gson().fromJson(npv,mp.getClass());
System.out.println(mp.get("employees").getClass().toString());
```

The json is given as input by user in string format(and it will always be a valid json string). And one thing is sure that I can't assume anything about the type of data. Because it will be provided by user.

So now actually I want that even If the user inputs something like arrays of string or arrays of objects. It should not convert the them to List,

Is there is a way I can hard code the type and keep them in `Map<String,String>`. so in the above example when I do `map.get("employees")` it should give me the `[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]` as string not list. I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: "When I use gson parser to convert that to a Map<String,String> map." Why would you do that? You don't *have* a string to string mapping - you effectively have a `Map<String, Object>` where the value for `employees` is a list... Why would you *expect* GSON to convert the natural list in your JSON into a string?

Comment: @JonSkeet, actually There is one more for loop which loops over all `map Entry` and try to print them out to the user. and If that is object I can't guess anything about that object(and If I can, then to print I have to myself check and move deep into the json and print them one by one, which will look like dfs). Assume the data is like `{k1:A1,k2:A2,k3:S1}` where k1,k2,k3,S1 are string and A1,A2 is arrays. I dont care what user enter in those array just keep the data as `String`. So when printing I can print the data by just looping over all entries of map. Thanks for help.

Comment: So make it a `Map<String, Object>` and just call `toString()` on the value. But don't expect the GSON parser to lose that information for you...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thank you so much. That worked.

Answer (score -1):

Jon is right, just use `Map<String, Object>`

```
String npv = json_string_provided_above;
Map<String,Object> mp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mp = new Gson().fromJson(npv, mp.getClass());
System.out.println(mp.get("employees").toString());
```